# Load Config File Issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I am trying get values for string Constants from config.properties file in Spring boot application. But when i am trying to access those values from java classes and coming as null.

Please find the code as below:

### Config.properties file:

```
## user Details##
user.username=xyz
user.password=123456


##customer Details  ##
customer.username=abc
customer.password=123456
```

### ConfigProp class:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ConfigProp {
    @Value("${user.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${user.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${customer.username}")
    private String custUserName;

    @Value("${customer.password}")
    private String custPassowrd;
}
```

### Test Class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ConfigProp configProp = new ConfigProp();
        System.out.println(configProp.getUserName());//coming as null
    }
}
```

SpringBoot App main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am not getting the issue exactly , why values are not coming. Can anyone please help me on this and let me know in case of any other details required.

Comment: Are you sure that the `config.properties` is at the class path?

Comment: Yes, config.properties is available in src/main/resources folder. thanks @ Harshit Shrivastava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem here:

```
ConfigProp configProp = new ConfigProp();
```

You are not letting spring maintain this dependency and hence its not recognizing this as `bean`.

You `Test`class can look like this:

```
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    ConfigProp configProp;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(configProp.getUserName());//coming as null
    }
}
```

The second problem here is presence of two main methods. You should write your `Test` class as Junit test which would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    ConfigProp configProp;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertEquals("abc", configProp.getCustUserName());
    }

}
```

Also `Test` class should be located in `src/test/java` location.

Comment: Can I know see your main class which has @SpringBootApplication annotation?

Comment: Added SpringBootApplication main class to the post.Please check.Thanks @Shanu Gupta

Comment: Saw it. hey is your Test class a junit test? Can you post a screenshot of your project structure as well? I'm just curious how you have two main methods?

Comment: I just added Test class with main() to test whether the values are coming  or  not . then i will delete the test class.Thanks

Comment: hmm... You should not write tests like that. Are you using spring-web?

Comment: Yes, @Shanu Gupta

Comment: Please let me know how to use it as trying in springboot main class also but it's throwing error as below:Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException @ Shanu Gupta

Comment: Added the test class.

Comment: Actually i will use those values in our code when ever required. now for testing whether vlaues are coming or not due to that created test class. So please let me know the usage in real class not for test class. so that i will use the same. Thanks @Shanu Gupta

Comment: @RajeswariReddy you can simple autowire the `ConfigProp` anywhere you want it to be available.